# Python - Retrieve file for a browser page's <input type="file"> through a filepath (or any alternative)

Tags: python, selenium, file-upload, browser, upload

I'm trying to automate uploading a file into a browser page through Python in Terminal. The browser page's code has

```
<input type="file" id="upload_input"/>
```

which opens an OS level dialog box, where I'm getting stuck. Is there a way to somehow override the OS level dialog box that opens by pointing it to a filepath or any alternative using Python? I'm overriding because I've been using Selenium to interact with the browser page and my code gets stuck here, where I have to interact with an OS level dialog box.

Note: the page isn't my page so I can't go in and change the html code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("upload_input").send_keys(r"C:\path_to_file.txt")
driver.find_element_by_id("submit_button").click()
```

Comment: That worked sort of! I'm running into an issue separate from that but this was good. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the test file is located in the same folder as your test script you can use the following:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('upload_input').send_keys(os.getcwd()+"/testupload.xlsx")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[type="submit"]').click()
```

In this case, `os.getcwd()` locates the 'current working directory' which is where the test script is located. I add the filename with string concatenation, you can use the same method to add for instance a directory. Unlike explicit file paths (such as C:\temp\myfile.txt), this way will work regardless of your OS as long as the relative file structure is the same across the machines.

Comment: That worked sort of! I'm running into an issue separate from that but this was good. Thanks!